How to make sliding animation in ReactJS
I have developed this login page which has sign-in and sign-up sections in the same page and can be displayed by sliding animation through button clicking process.
When doing that process by JS file this an error message: cannot read

properties of null (reading 'addeventlistener')

This is the result I am looking for: https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkx-j0vr45zTq9YzXk5u_5ehYQOUErJqIoX?si=wSkcpjI2u7ze-sPt
function Login() {
  return (
    <div className='login_container' id='container'>
      <div className='form-container sing-up'>
        <form>
          <h1>Create Account</h1>
          <div className='social-icons'>
            <i><Fas.FaGooglePlusG /></i>
            <i><Fas.FaFacebook /></i>
          </div>
          <span>O usa tu email para registrarte</span>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Nombre' />
          <input type='text' placeholder='Email' />
          <input type='text' placeholder='Password' />
          <button>Sign Up</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className='form-container sing-in'>
        <form>
          <h1>Sign In </h1>
          <div className='social-icons'>
            <i><Fas.FaGooglePlusG /></i>
            <i><Fas.FaFacebook /></i>
          </div>
          <span>O usa tu email para registrarte</span>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Nombre' />
          <input type='text' placeholder='Email' />
          <input type='text' placeholder='Password' />
          <button>Sign In</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className='toogle-container'>
        <div className='toogle'>
          <div className='toogle-panel toogle-left'>
            <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
            <p>Enter your personal details to use all of site features</p>
            <button className='hidden' id='login'>Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <div className='toogle-panel toogle-right'>
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
            <p>Register with your personal email or social media </p>
            <button className='hidden' id='register'>Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src='script.js'></script>
 </div>
  
  )
}

export default Login

const container = document.getElementById('container');
const registerBtn = document.getElementById('register');
const loginBtn = document.getElementById('login');


registerBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    container.classList.add("active");
});

loginBtn.removeEventListener('click', ()=> {
    container.classList.remove("active");
});



Unrelated to this problem, but generally important: In React you should avoid mutating the DOM. So, instead of classList.add("active"), use a React state, and add the class as part of the render: className={\login_container ${ activeState ? 'active' : '' }`}`

The part at the end doesn't look like react code?

How does this work? You export the function Login. Then the code below assumes the HTML elements already exist. Wait with your event listener calls until the DOM has finished loading.

What I displayed below was the JS File but I think there is another way (the correct way) to make it in ReactJS. What I am trying to achieve is this sliding animation displayed in this sample link below: https://www.youtube.com/clip/Ugkx-j0vr45zTq9YzXk5u_5ehYQOUErJqIoX  Your comments would be helpful. Thanks for your great support

For making this type of animation  you may need to use useRef and classList.add() .First of all create ref for login and sign up
 const signInFormRef = useRef(null);
 const loginFormRef = useRef(null);

Then assign ref to each of them
   {/* Sign In Form will be active by default*/}
    <form ref={signInFormRef} className={`form active`}>
    ...
    {/* Login Form */}
    <form ref={loginFormRef} className={`form`}>
    ...

After that create a handler for each button.
  const handleLogInButton = () => {
     signInFormRef.current.classList.remove("active");
     loginFormRef.current.classList.add("active");
  }
  const handlesignUpButton = () => {
     signInFormRef.current.classList.add("active");
     loginFormRef.current.classList.remove("active");
  }

Add a active class in css having all proerties.
But this will apply same properties to both for having move to opposite direction you need to make 2 classes activelogin and activesignup
  const handleLogInButton = () => {
     signInFormRef.current.classList.remove("activesignup");
     loginFormRef.current.classList.add("activelogin");
  }
  const handlesignUpButton = () => {
     signInFormRef.current.classList.add("activesignup");
     loginFormRef.current.classList.remove("activelogin");
  }        

Make sure to make this change in signup form
   {/* Sign In Form will be active by default*/}
    <form ref={signInFormRef} className={`form activesignup`}>
    ...

Hope this helps...
